# Execute SOAP xml request

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, textbox

So in my company we use SOAP API to get connect to our system, and I'm pretty well rehearsed in it and can use all the calls.

I just want to know where should I start if I want to build a test landing page that can execute the API queries.

I would prefer to do it with JavaScript if that is possible as we don't have PHP installed on our servers.

Looking for some direction of where to start - I'm simply going to take a value from a text box and place within the XML request and execute it :)

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function fireRequest(){

            ..
            //parse your SOAP Request and set the request with 'dataContent'
            ...

            var url = //your target gateway here Java/PHP or your web service recpetor
            var postStr =//xml SOAP resquest ;
            makeRequest(url, postStr);
            }

    function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Mozilla, Safari ...
         } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //IE
         } else {
            alert("Your Browser does not support XMLHTTP");

         }
     }
    function makeRequest(url, param) {
    //If our readystate is either not started or finished, initiate a new request
        //clearing all divs
        receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
        if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {

           //Set up the connection to captcha_test.html. True sets the request to asyncronous(default) 
           receiveReq.open("POST", url, true);
           //Set the function that will be called when the XmlHttpRequest objects state changes
           receiveReq.onreadystatechange = responseHandler; 

           //Add HTTP headers to the request
           receiveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           receiveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
           receiveReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
           //Make the request
           receiveReq.send(param);
        }   
    }
    function responseHandler(){

        if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {


            var response = receiveReq.responseText;
            if(response){
            //do what ever you want with the response XML


            }   
        }
    }
</script>
```

This would be enough for your case. use the methods at your page.